# want citations only in the list using printbibliography and not in paragraph

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, luatex, citing, biber

I want to include publication list in my resume for that I am using this

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\begin{document}

\begin{rSection}{Publications}
\cite{bhooshan1,bhooshan3,bhooshan4}
\printbibliography[type=article,title={Journal Papers}]
\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

now the problem is this. I don't want the numbers appearing after the heading "Publications". I only want the final list. 
Is it possible to supress them?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Try `\nocite{bhooshan1,bhooshan3,bhooshan4}` or `\nocite{*}` to list all entries in your `.bib` file.

Comment: Thank you !! It works !!!